# About receiving funds from someone else's account from overseas bank

Tags: scams

Yesterday a woman sent me a friend request request. And I accepted it ..She said on messenger that she has to share something to me and gave me her Gmail account...I started talking to her on that she told me that she is alone ..There is no one of her ...She is suffering from cancer over 2 moths ..She said her life almost ended.that is why she wants to distribute her funds in the church of Europe,Asia and Africa.she told that she was dreaming my name over a week... She said that she has chosen me from out of thousands of people..She keeps emailing me at night.. Since two days...And has sent me all her photos of hospital...She has sent me her bank email id so that I can email the bank as a next of kin of her...Sir what should i do???Do I mail?Plz reply me asap.. Thanks

Comment: This is a scam. Delete the emails and never respond to "her" again.

Answer (score 9):

This is a scam.

Delete the email and don't talk to the person or keep any contact.

Answer (score 2):

Ask yourself one question - "Why me?"

Say I had no friends or family (that I liked). I have money and I'm dying. There are a half dozen charities I'd write checks to. Under what circumstances would I ever contact a stranger to try to give my money away? That answers why this is a scam.